# Get current url path

Tags: php, laravel

How many examples I have not seen, all are essentially the same, and perform the same thing. Let's take a look at one of them.

```
Route::current()->uri()
```

We have url `https://example.com/test` and we get `test`, and in all examples the same

But how to make sure that we get not just `test` but with a slash `/test`?

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin no, with full url, I want to get this part `/test`, together with a slash

Comment: Are you trying to use this, or are you just inspecting this?

Comment: @Chu I think I saw something as you want, let me see.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I want to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with this piece of code:

```
request()->getPathInfo();
```

Laravel `Illuminate/Http/Request` extends Symfony `Request` class which contains `getPathInfo` method.

> Docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#identifying-a-request

Definition of that method you can find [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.3/Request.php#L855).

Comment: yes it worked, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

### You can get url in laravel :

```php
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();

// Get the full URL for the previous request...
echo url()->previous();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
request()->getPathInfo();
```

You can find the method definition [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.3/Request.php#L855)